# JS Getting variables from calling html

Tags: javascript, variables, parameter-passing

I am setting up the following code to allow me decide which JS functions/files to run based on conditional PHP echos to the array given. For some reason I seem unable to retrieve the contents of the array in the Javascript code given:

**HTML**

```
<!-- add functions to run at window.onload here -->
<script type="text/javascript">
on_multiload [0] = "message";
on_multiload [1] = "message2";

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ondesign.org.uk/wp-content/plugins/on-dev-kit/js/pageload.js"></script>
```

**JS**

```
window.onload = function () {
    on_multiFunction_load (on_multiload);
}

function on_multiFunction_load (on_multiload) {
    for (var i = 0; i< on_multiload.length; i++) {
        alert (on_multiload[i]);
    }
}
```

Can anyone see what I've done wrong (first time loading js variables from an external source, so it's likely to be simple)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to assign values to properties of `on_multiload` while `on_multiload` is `undefined`.

```
var on_multiload = [];
on_multiload[0] = "message";
on_multiload[1] = "message2";
```

or

```
var on_multiload = [ "message", "message2" ];
```

Comment: Cheers! That was all I needed.

Comment: OK, this is now 100% functional.